# Is it useless to use the Lock() in multiprocess Pool()?

Tags: multiprocessing, global-variables, python-3.6, pool

In my python3 multiprocess program, I need a global variable `COUNT` for counting. I use the Manager.Lock() to maintain global variable `COUNT` to prevent conflicts when child-processes write this variable.
Following is my code implementation;

```
# Ubuntu 16.04 LTS, python 3.6
from multiprocessing import Pool, Lock, Manager
COUNT = 0
def f(lock,x):
    global COUNT
    with lock:
        COUNT += x
        print(COUNT,end=' ')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    manager = Manager()
    lock = manager.Lock()
    print('Origin COUNT:',COUNT)
    print('COUNT in child-process:',end=' ')
    with Pool(4) as pool:
        for i in [2,4,6,8,10]:
            pool.apply(func=f,args=(lock,i))
        pool.close()
        pool.join()
        print()
        print('Final COUNT:',COUNT)

# result
Origin COUNT: 0
COUNT in child-process: 6 4 8 2 12 
Final COUNT: 0
```

It is clear that:

1. child processes operate on the same variable `COUNT`.
2. the operation on global variables `COUNT` by each child process is **Not all saved**.(WHY?)

Final COUNT is 0??? Shouldn't the result be 30? (`sum([2,4,6,8,10])`)
This really confuses me. Lock() failed?

Comment: I don’t think subprocesses can change a global variable in the main program.

Comment: @mkrieger1 You enlightened me on the issue! The parent and child processes must have different namespaces. Thanks! By the way, do you have any suggestions for this implementation?